# Add feature to Audit Trail Module to store value of Changed Item

Tags: logging

I am trying to add a feature on this module - 
http://klpatil.github.io/Sitecore-Audit-Trail/ 
so that I can store the old and new changed value of the Sitecore Item in the Logs Table.
But I am not sure how to get the old value. Anyone done this before ? I am on Sitecore 8.1

Comment: It should be in the message. Was {xxxx} now {yyyy}

Comment: Its not there in the Message.  @ChrisAuer